# handlers main.yml showing error handlers/main.yml file must contain list of tasks

Tags: ansible, ansible-role

I am building some role in handlers/main.yml I had spacified some handler jobs but I was unable to execute them. This is the error message:

> ERROR! The handlers/main.yml file for role 'sample-mysql' must contain
>   a list of tasks

The error appears to be in '/home/automation/plays/roles/sample-mysql/handlers/main.yml': line 2, column 3, but maybe somewhere else in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

```
The offending line appears to be:

---
  handlers:
  ^ here
```

I had  done some changes but still  not working. I also want this file to load handlers from another file. Is it possible to do so? such as - include: directive

```
---
  handlers:
  - name: "Start mysql"
    service:
      enabled: true
      name: mysqld
      state: started
  - name: "Start firewalld"
    service:
      enabled: true
      name: firewalld
      state: started
```

> ERROR! The handlers/main.yml file for role 'sample-mysql' must contain
>   a list of tasks

The error appears to be in '/home/automation/plays/roles/sample-mysql/handlers/main.yml': line 2, column 3, but maybe somewhere else in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

```
---
  handlers:
  ^ here
```

Comment: How am I supposed to help you if you don't include your actual code in the question (for the first part)? For the second part there seems to be some code but I cannot read it because it's all on one line, can you please format it to be readable?

Answer (score 1):

The handler file location is  **/repo_name/roles/sample-mysql/handlers/main.yaml**
Inside the main.yaml add the below contents.

```
---
- name: Start mysql
  service:
   name: mysqld
   state: started
   enabled: true
```

To call this handler include the below line in your main playbook, **/repo_name/roles/sample-mysql/tasks/main.yaml**

```
notify: "Restart iis service"
```

You cannot simply execute a handler. Inside the sample-mysql folder, there should be folders called tasks and handlers.

Comment: Thanks asha i got it

Answer (score 0):

In your role, there is file: `handlers/main.yml`.
Edit that file, and add this task:

```
---
- name: a task
  shell: echo
```

save it

Answer (score 0):

If you use a separate file like handlers/main.yml, you must omit the keyword "handlers:". You will only need that keyword, if you put all in one role file.