# Ansible task with handler fails with unexpected parameter type in action class ansible.parsing.yaml.objects.AnsibleSequence

Tags: ansible

This is one of my Ansible files:

```yaml
---
- name: Harden sshd configuration
  tasks:
  - name: Update /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    lineinfile:
      path: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
      regex: "{{ item.find }}"
      line: "{{ item.replace }}"
    loop:
      - { find: '^(# *)?ChallengeResponseAuthentication (yes|no)', replace: 'ChallengeResponseAuthentication no' }
      - { find: '^(# *)?PasswordAuthentication (yes|no)', replace: 'PasswordAuthentication no' }
      - { find: '^(# *)?PermitRootLogin (yes|no)', replace: 'PermitRootLogin no' }
      - { find: '^(# *)?UsePAM (yes|no)', replace: 'UsePAM no' }
    notify:
      - Restart sshd

  handlers:
    - name: Restart sshd
      service:
        name: sshd
        state: restarted
```

It's used for provisioning in Packer.

When the file runs, I get this error:

> unexpected parameter type in action: <class 'ansible.parsing.yaml.objects.AnsibleSequence'>

```
==> amazon-ebs: Provisioning with Ansible...
    amazon-ebs: Setting up proxy adapter for Ansible....
==> amazon-ebs: Executing Ansible: ansible-playbook -e packer_build_name="amazon-ebs" -e packer_builder_type=amazon-ebs --ssh-extra-args '-o IdentitiesOnly=yes' -e ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/tmp/ansible-key218178175 -i /tmp/packer-provisioner-ansible080932818 /home/amedee/repos/packer-ansible-aws-linux/packer/provisioners/ansible/ansible_playbook.yml
    amazon-ebs:
    amazon-ebs: PLAY [Jenkins node playbook] ***************************************************
    amazon-ebs:
    amazon-ebs: TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
    amazon-ebs: ok: [default]
    amazon-ebs:
    amazon-ebs: TASK [include_tasks] ***********************************************************
    amazon-ebs: fatal: [default]: FAILED! => {"reason": "unexpected parameter type in action: <class 'ansible.parsing.yaml.objects.AnsibleSequence'>\n\nThe error appears to be in '/home/amedee/repos/packer-ansible-aws-linux/packer/provisioners/ansible/configure_sshd.yml': line 2, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n---\n- name: Harden sshd configuration\n  ^ here\n"}
    amazon-ebs:
    amazon-ebs: PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
    amazon-ebs: default                    : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
    amazon-ebs:
==> amazon-ebs: Provisioning step had errors: Running the cleanup provisioner, if present...
```

---

When I change it to

```yaml
---
- name: Harden sshd configuration
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    regex: "{{ item.find }}"
    line: "{{ item.replace }}"
  loop:
    - { find: '^(# *)?ChallengeResponseAuthentication (yes|no)', replace: 'ChallengeResponseAuthentication no' }
    - { find: '^(# *)?PasswordAuthentication (yes|no)', replace: 'PasswordAuthentication no' }
    - { find: '^(# *)?PermitRootLogin (yes|no)', replace: 'PermitRootLogin no' }
    - { find: '^(# *)?UsePAM (yes|no)', replace: 'UsePAM no' }
  notify:
    - Restart sshd

  handlers:
    - name: Restart sshd
      service:
        name: sshd
        state: restarted
```

Then I get this error:

> conflicting action statements: lineinfile, handlers

```
==> amazon-ebs: Provisioning with Ansible...
    amazon-ebs: Setting up proxy adapter for Ansible....
==> amazon-ebs: Executing Ansible: ansible-playbook -e packer_build_name="amazon-ebs" -e packer_builder_type=amazon-ebs --ssh-extra-args '-o IdentitiesOnly=yes' -e ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/tmp/ansible-key210397388 -i /tmp/packer-provisioner-ansible927349691 /home/amedee/repos/packer-ansible-aws-linux/packer/provisioners/ansible/ansible_playbook.yml
    amazon-ebs:
    amazon-ebs: PLAY [Jenkins node playbook] ***************************************************
    amazon-ebs:
    amazon-ebs: TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
    amazon-ebs: ok: [default]
    amazon-ebs:
    amazon-ebs: TASK [include_tasks] ***********************************************************
    amazon-ebs: fatal: [default]: FAILED! => {"reason": "conflicting action statements: lineinfile, handlers\n\nThe error appears to be in '/home/amedee/repos/packer-ansible-aws-linux/packer/provisioners/ansible/configure_sshd.yml': line 2, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n---\n- name: Harden sshd configuration\n  ^ here\n"}
    amazon-ebs:
    amazon-ebs: PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
    amazon-ebs: default                    : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
    amazon-ebs:
==> amazon-ebs: Provisioning step had errors: Running the cleanup provisioner, if present...
```

---

And with this file:

```yaml
---
tasks:
  - name: Harden sshd configuration
    lineinfile:
      path: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
      regex: "{{ item.find }}"
      line: "{{ item.replace }}"
    loop:
      - { find: '^(# *)?ChallengeResponseAuthentication (yes|no)', replace: 'ChallengeResponseAuthentication no' }
      - { find: '^(# *)?PasswordAuthentication (yes|no)', replace: 'PasswordAuthentication no' }
      - { find: '^(# *)?PermitRootLogin (yes|no)', replace: 'PermitRootLogin no' }
      - { find: '^(# *)?UsePAM (yes|no)', replace: 'UsePAM no' }
    notify:
      - Restart sshd

handlers:
  - name: Restart sshd
    service:
      name: sshd
      state: restarted
```

I get this error:

> included task files must contain a list of tasks

```
==> amazon-ebs: Provisioning with Ansible...
    amazon-ebs: Setting up proxy adapter for Ansible....
==> amazon-ebs: Executing Ansible: ansible-playbook -e packer_build_name="amazon-ebs" -e packer_builder_type=amazon-ebs --ssh-extra-args '-o IdentitiesOnly=yes' -e ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/tmp/ansible-key347362703 -i /tmp/packer-provisioner-ansible498794402 /home/amedee/repos/packer-ansible-aws-linux/packer/provisioners/ansible/ansible_playbook.yml
    amazon-ebs:
    amazon-ebs: PLAY [Jenkins node playbook] ***************************************************
    amazon-ebs:
    amazon-ebs: TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
    amazon-ebs: ok: [default]
    amazon-ebs:
    amazon-ebs: TASK [include_tasks] ***********************************************************
    amazon-ebs: fatal: [default]: FAILED! => {"reason": "included task files must contain a list of tasks"}
    amazon-ebs:
    amazon-ebs: PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
    amazon-ebs: default                    : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
    amazon-ebs:
==> amazon-ebs: Provisioning step had errors: Running the cleanup provisioner, if present...
```

I'm pretty sure that it's an annoyingly simple syntax error, but I could really use some extra sets of eyes to find it.

Answer (score 0):

I got rid of the handler and now it works:

```
---
- name: Harden sshd configuration
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    regex: "{{ item.find }}"
    line: "{{ item.replace }}"
  loop:
    - {find: '^(# *)?ChallengeResponseAuthentication (yes|no)',
       replace: 'ChallengeResponseAuthentication no'}
    - {find: '^(# *)?PasswordAuthentication (yes|no)',
       replace: 'PasswordAuthentication no'}
    - {find: '^(# *)?PermitRootLogin (yes|no)',
       replace: 'PermitRootLogin no'}
    - {find: '^(# *)?UsePAM (yes|no)',
       replace: 'UsePAM no'}

- name: Restart sshd
  service:
    name: sshd
    state: restarted
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I got same problem as you described and I would guess you have same structure for your playbooks as described here:

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html

to get rid of this error you need to create separate folder and file for handlers and add code there  `handlers/main.yml`

similar to:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/57145578/5492644

At least this is how I fixed my issue.